# Use variable for DB name to generate views

Tags: sql-server

I have numerous cross DB **Views**. Would like to modify using a variable for the DB name.

e.g.
Current:

```
SELECT     field1, field2, field3, field4
FROM         companyDB2.dbo.Company_Users AS Company_Users_1
```

Want:
(PSEUDO CODE)

```
'SELECT     field1, field2, field3, field4  FROM '  
+  @companyDBname 
+  '.dbo.Company_Users'
```

Am I better off using a **Table Valued UDF?**

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is all or nothing...

```
set @sql = 'SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM ' + @companyDBname + '.dbo.Company_Users AS Company_Users_1'

exec @sql
```

There are quite a few security risks in allowing exec usage (SQL injection), be wary of that and do a little research

Comment: Appreciate your attempt. I don't think you understood what I was trying to accomplish. Please let me explain.

I am trying to introduce a dynamic element to the <b>view</b> definition. Primarily: the (external) schema that it will be referencing.

A view definition will not accept an execute command or a Parameter (hence my pseudo) 

I am of the believe that I will have to scrap the views and try using A User Defined Function (that will accept a parameter)

P.S. I am also painfully aware of SQL injections. Thanks